# Как работает std::is_convertible<U (*)[], T (*)[]>::value?

Tags: c++

Копался в файлах chromium-a и наткнулся вот на [этот](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:base/containers/checked_iterators.h;l=57;bpv=0;bpt=1)

Вот кусочек, в котором происходит **какая-то магия**.

```
  template <
      typename U,
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U (*)[], T (*)[]>::value>* = nullptr>
  constexpr CheckedContiguousIterator(const CheckedContiguousIterator<U>& other)
      : start_(other.start_), current_(other.current_), end_(other.end_) {
    // We explicitly don't delegate to the 3-argument constructor here. Its
    // CHECKs would be redundant, since we expect |other| to maintain its own
    // invariant. However, DCHECKs never hurt anybody. Presumably.
    DCHECK_LE(other.start_, other.current_);
    DCHECK_LE(other.current_, other.end_);
  }
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит вот в этой строке:

```
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U (*)[], T (*)[]>::value>* = nullptr>
```

- почему " = nullptr"?
- что такое "U (*)[]" и как оно работает?

Comment: `U (*)[]` - это указатель на массив неопределенного количества U, а что эта должно делать - описано в комментарии

Comment: Вы очень неудачно срезали комментарий перед функцией. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> почему " = nullptr"?

Нипочему. Ну то есть могло бы быть написано по-другому, не меняя сути.

'std::enable_if_t' используется как шаблонный параметр для SFINAE, если подстановка первого параметра для неудачна, 'std::enable_if_t' не скомпилируется и функция выбросится. В случае удачной подстановки, `enable_if_t` является `typedef` для своего второго шаблонного параметра, который по умолчанию void. Чтобы в функции не было лишних шаблонных параметров, параметр, образованный `enable_if_t` делают по умолчанию. Вариантов много:

- `enable_if_t<..., void>* = nullptr` - более длинная запись того, что в исходном примере
- `enable_if_t<..., int> = 0` - вариант с шаблонным параметром int
- `class = enable_if_t<...>` - вариант с шаблонным параметром типом

> что такое "U (*)[]" и как оно работает?

Указатель на массив. По ссылке в комментарии объяснение.